# How to download only specific types of attachments using JavaMail

Tags: java, csv, email, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am trying to download the attachments from Outlook mail using JavaMail.

I am able to download all the attachments in the mail but I want to restrict that. All I want to do is download only CSV format file if its present in the mail as attachment. If there are any other format of attachments do not download it just ignore.

With following code I am able to download all the attachments present in the mail and I tried few things but none seems to work properly.
Can you guys please help me how to download only attached CSV file using JavaMail?

```
if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
        // content may contain attachments
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
        int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
        for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                // this part is attachment
                String fileName = part.getFileName();
                attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
            } else {
                // this part may be the message content
                messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
            }
        }

        if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
            attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
        }
    } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain") || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
        Object content = message.getContent();
        if (content != null) {
            messageContent = content.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific than _"none seems to work properly"_. We need to know what your problem is so we can help you. We are not here to execute your code and then guess at your problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The for loop that I have used in that  I tried checking if there is any Content Type for "message" but not getting anything useful there.
I tried checking the System.out.println(multiPart.getContentType()); but no luck there as well.

Comment: Also I tried checking various functions available for "part" to see if anywhere I can get the attached file type but no luck there also.

Comment: If the file is sent using the official MIME type text/csv, you can check for that.  But most likely they're just text/plain.  Unless you know that the file name has a particular extension (e.g., ".csv"), you'll have to look inside each text/plain attachment and try to guess whether the data in the attachment is a csv format file or not.